# Как поместить в список слова, которые стоят после каждого двоеточия

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, генераторы

На ввод подается строка, состоящая из пар число:слово, по типу:

```
70:ztuebs 0:zdhkpq 54:jkyfmo 16:ducsvpq 85:ntsaw
```

Мне необходимо в одну строчку написать код, который поместит в список только слова из строки. Я пытался сделать так:

```
a = [input().split(':')[1]]
```

но код не работает правильно, он пишет слово после двоеточия, но только одно и как бы ещё пишет уже продолжение  строки, включая все числа и слова и даже двоеточие. Оно понятно, потому что строка одна и программа отрезает только ту часть, которая стоит до первого двоеточие, а ещё она не учитывает, что после каждого пробела надо заново просматривать элемент и на выходе получается так:

```
['ztuebs 0']
```

а мне нужен такой результат:

```
['ztuebs', 'zdhkpq', 'jkyfmo', 'ducsvpq', 'ntsaw']
```

как можно код улучшить? Нельзя использовать `set`, `list`, `dict`. Но можно использовать `for` и `if` и так далее, главное чтобы **в одну строчку** уложилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

алгоритм:

1. разбейте строку на слова по разделителю `' '`
2. пройдитесь по всем словам и разбейте их на слова по разделителю `':'`
3. в новый массив добавьте вторые слова из разбиения 2)

вариант 1:

```
text = "70:ztuebs 0:zdhkpq 54:jkyfmo 16:ducsvpq 85:ntsaw"

res = list(map(lambda obj: obj.split(':')[1], text.split()))

print(res)
```

вариант 2:

```
res = [*map(lambda obj: obj.split(':')[1], text.split())]
```

вариант 3:

```
res = [i.split(':')[1] for i in text.split()]
```

Comment: К сожалению список использовать нельзя, я имею ввиду метод list()

Comment: а `[*map(lambda obj: obj.split(':')[1], text.split())]`?

Comment: сработало, спасибо за алгоритм

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "70:ztuebs 0:zdhkpq 54:jkyfmo 16:ducsvpq 85:ntsaw" 

[x.split(':').pop() for x in s.split()]
```

есди нельзя pop(), напишите x.split()[1]

Comment: сработало, также полезный вариант